# error:no such partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, windows-7

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 / Windows 7 dual boot. I resized the partition in Windows 7, and after that every time I start my laptop I get `error: no such partition`.

[image]

I tried these two methods to solve this:

1. Set boot and prefix but after insmod normal I got the same error `no such partition`.
2. Tried to boot Ubuntu using bootable file and ran these 2 commands:

   ```
   sudo apt install lilo   
   sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr
   ```

but after restarting my laptop I got a `no such partition found` error again.

Comment: @K7AAY this works: `lsblk | grep -v "loop"|"tmpfs" && df -h | grep -v "loop"|"tmpfs"
`

Comment: @K7AAY sir i am using ubuntu 16.04 sorry for the wrong tag and when i paste your  command  on terminal it give " tempfs:command not found".

Comment: @oldfred sir when i try to paste your command on terminal it gives an error i.e                        No command 'tmpfs' found, did you mean:
 Command 'tmfs' from package 'tmfs' (universe)
 Command 'mtpfs' from package 'mtpfs' (universe)
tmpfs: command not found

Comment: this was the command that worked: `lsblk | grep -v 'tmpfs|/dev/loop' && df -h | grep -v 'tmpfs|/dev/loop'` Not sure how it changed when I posted it. Just copied back to my terminal. One above does not work, but this one does. ??

Comment: tmpfs is not a command. that line asks grep to remove any device named tempfs. See https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/ if you need an explanation of grep.

Comment: @oldfred sir what to do after that command ......i paste that command on my ubuntu(bootable LIve USB) and it shows  '" File system , size, used, Avail, used%, mounted on" what to do after that or sir if you can give me your email i can send you its Screenshot

Comment: @K7AAY sir the output of your command is  "tempfs: command not found" .......sir my laptop running on a dual boot successfully after that i try to resize the partition in windows after that when i try to start the laptop its enter in GRUB RESCUE mode

Comment: Copy & paste above in your question to preserve formatting. Do not post screen shot. Then we know partitions, type and amount used.

Comment: From the Ubuntu LiveUSB, run _lsblk | grep -v "loop" && df -h | grep -v "loop"_ to bypass the problem you have with typing the prior command , highlight the resulting text, copy the text with Ctrl-Shift-C then return here, click edit, and paste the result in the question so we can see what has been done to the partitions on the drive. There will be _tempfs_ devices in the list of drive devices; we will ignore them and concentrate on the rest.

Comment: @oldfred  sir please find the screenshot of the command in question  in " ScreenShot of Command"

Comment: Pllase do not post screenshots of the terminal. Copy the output from the terminal and paste it directly into your question. Then format the pasted output as `code` using the { } icon above the edit question menu.

Comment: Your sda1 is not showing. lets get more info. Only post link, not report. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred sir i don't know how Boot-Repair is supposed to work but it but it safely remove ubuntu from my laptop and after that i reinstall Ubuntu in my laptop . thank you sir for your help